# problema com caminho de arquivo PHP

Tags: php, mysql, require

Boa noite, estou tendo problemas ao fazer include de um arquivo que utilizo para cadastrar dados no meu banco, estou recebendo o erro: **Warning: require(./cadastro/usuario/usuario.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projeto_biblioteca\validadores\validador_usuario\validar_usuario.php on line 5**.
 Estou no arquivo validadores/validar_usuario/validar_usuario.php e estou tentando incluir neste arquivo o caminho do arquivo usuario.php que está desta forma: cadastro/usuario/usuario.php conforme imagem abaixo, este arquivo é minha classe de cadastrar usuarios no banco e o arquivo validar_usuario.php é pra onde eu estou enviando os dados do meu form e fazendo include da minha classe de cadastro, gostaria de um help para especificar o caminho de maneira correta já que tentei varias formas e ainda não resolvi o problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base na estrutura do projeto apresentada na imagem da pergunta, você terá que voltar 2 níveis no seu **require**. Note que se você voltar somente 1 nível, realmente não vai existir no seu projeto ***"Projeto_biblioteca/validadores/cadastro/usuario/usuario.php"***.

```
require('../../cadastro/Usuario/usuario.php');
```

De qualquer maneira você poderia referenciar ao diretório raiz da aplicação (dê uma olhada em [*$_SERVER*](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php) - DOCUMENT_ROOT) para evitar problemas em migrar sua aplicação para outros diretórios e sistemas.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá amigo, obrigado pelo help ajudou aqui, agora estou estudando um pouco o autoload.php do Composer pra carregar minhas classes, será que fica mais fácil?

Comment: Com certeza o auto_load do Composer irá lhe ajudar ainda mais, poderá facilitar com os namespaces. @wilder, a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta é marcando ela como aceita, clicando no sinal de visto (✓). Mas faça isso apenas se alguma resposta tiver respondido sua dúvida original. Quando atingir 15 pontos de reputação também poderá [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta. Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar o diretório anterior, no Windows faça `"../"` e não `"./"`.
Por exemplo: `include('../Cadastro/Usuario/usuario.php');`